# How to reverse this normalization

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering

Can any one help me please to reverse the following normalization?

```
image_normalized = uint8(255*mat2gray(image));
```

This command normalizes a matrix values to 0-255. So, after doing some filtering (denoising), how can I transform the new filtered values from 0-255 to the original value space?

Comment: Very basic stuff. Please show your attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not exactly how mat2gray works, but I think that it perfomrs a "contrast expansion".

```
Ioutput[i,j] = ( Iinput[i,j]-min  )* K / (max - min)
```

where min = min(Iinput(:)) and max = max(Iinput(:)) , and K is a constant.

And what you can do to reverse the normalization is to find K and save the max and min value of the input image.

On the other hand, if you are dealing with noise you should consider that the min or max value could be a corrupted pixel.